# How do I waterproof a wood door?

Tags: doors, waterproofing, outdoor

I'm replacing a shed door.  Nothing fancy and I didn't want to spend a lot, so I didn't invest a lot on an exterior door.

Instead, I have a hollow core wood door blank to which I've applied two coats of primer and one coat (so far) of exterior flat paint.

While it's not a huge deal if the door only lasts a few years, I'd like to do whatever I can to prolong its life as much as possible.  What further treatment can I give the door to help extend its life?

Comment: Be sure to throw extra extra extra coats on the bottom, top, and lockset cutouts of the door. Don't let those surfaces get stripped of paint by grinding against the jamb. You might even consider fabricating a tiny drip cap at the top to keep water from drooling down the face of the door.

Comment: I will lay the paint on the top and bottom extra thick.  No lockset cutout - using a gate latch on the door with a padlock.  By drip cap do you mean over the sill?  Or on the door itself like a C over the top of the door?

Comment: I was thinking of something on the top of the door jamb... ping back if you want a picture.

Answer (score 2):

Metal and/or fully adhered rubber flashing and drip edge on top of door trim placed under siding.  Oil based finish to door and frame.  Seal bottom and side edges of door with oil based finish.